# C++ / objective c thread call losing parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

Our code has just started crashing due to a thread calling a memory alloc function and losing the pointer to the memory pool.

The pointer is initialised before the threads are started, but when the thread uses it to call the memory alloc code, it's zero.

In out init code we have

```
poolptr = InitMemoryPool ()
```

This sets it to a non zero memory address

In our .mm code on the thread we have

```
unsigned byte * p=(unsigned byte * ) MyAlloc ( poolptr, amount )
```

When the code gets into the MyAlloc function, poolptr is 0

Do I need my poolptr pointer to be volatile ? Even so, it's value is set up before the thread starts and never changes, so if the compiler is assuming it's a const, why doesn't it have it set correctly ?

Also, this has worked fine for years - and just started going wrong yesterday, simultaneously on two peoples machines.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There is a tag for objective c

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code. Is `poolptr` an instance variable? There are a lot of details missing from this question — [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This, what you mentioned, I don't do. What eventually worked for me is as follows:

I call my function or method and put in that function or method local instances of an class on the heap via command "new". Data that is to be returned is also paid respect to. Triggering a new thread will have access to that heap area if the heap area is a simple parameter. I.e., t= new thread( parameter);

```
void* function_or_method() {

clist *lstp;
string *_ps;
bool b;
    try {


    lstp= NULL;
           
            lstp= new clist;
            _ps= new string;
          
            lstp->set( (void *)_ps);


            mathclass *math;
            thread *_thread;
            
                         
            math= new mathclass();
            if((NULL==math))
                    throw Exception();
            b= math->set( lstp);
            
    if(! b) {
                    throw Exception();
            }

            _thread= new thread( math);
            _thread->join();

            delete _thread;
            _thread= NULL;

    } catch(const exception& e) {
            clog <<"exception: logging" <<endl;
    }
    
return (void*)lstp;
}
```

Okay, this is just C++ as well as C. I hope it will help a bit.

Comment: Our code is on the IOS and buried in our engine. I was trying to simplify the code - a minimal reproducible example would be a bit of a nightmare.

What I really wanted to know was could the compiler possibly be deciding - at compile time - that because the "poolptr" was not written to in the thread, that it could be assumed not to change, and be compiled out as a null pointer ?  It's part of a structure that is static/global, e.g. Engine.Memory.poolptr. It probably needs to be volatile, but it's worked as it is for the last 6-8 years. Why now ?

Comment: Volatile is known for me only when it comes to static initializers. Yes, as far as I know, it could also be static. The years that passed without error could be overthrown by updates and so.